# "None of that yielded any result" vs "None of that yielded any results"

Tags: word-choice

What's the correct/commonly used form?

Example sentence:

> When none of my begging yielded any result, I relied on threats.
>
> When none of my begging yielded any results, I relied on threats.

Or maybe there's no difference?

Comment: You might find your answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112996/any-followed-by-singular-or-plural-countable-nouns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the word **any** as a determiner for an unknown or indefinite quantity of something, it must be possible for the *something* to be interpreted as plural. Usually, for a countable noun, this means that the plural form must be used, but this is not always the case. For example:

> On my way to the birthday party I went to the bakery, hoping to pick up something to bring with me. Unfortunately, they didn't have **any cakes**, so I left empty handed.
>
> I arrived late at the party, and to my surprise I found there wasn't **any birthday cake** left, it had already been eaten! I found my friend and asked them, "Did you have **any cake**?".

In the first sentence, the plural "cakes" is used because I am saying that I expected there to be *some cakes*, but there weren't any. In the second sentence, the singular "cake" is used because I am expecting to have a *part* of a single cake, but none of that single cake is left.

---

**Any** can also be used to mean *whichever*, or *"it doesn't matter which"*:

> Pick **any** one you like.  *"Choose whichever one you like"*

Here, "any" is not referring to any particular number of things, so doesn't have to be plural, and is more usually used with singular countable nouns.

---

So the choice of "result" or "results" depends whether you are using *any* to mean "some unknown amount", and if so whether "result" can be interpreted as being more than singular (which would be contextual, "results" would be more likely to be appropriate), or to mean "whichever", in which case it would depend whether you expected a single "result" or multiple "results".